# Оптимизация простого sql запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующий sql запрос:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM product 
WHERE name LIKE '%para%' 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name LIKE 'para%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC LIMIT 50
```

Т.е. суть в том чтобы получить все продукты где есть совпадение в названии, но нужно отсортировать их таким образом чтобы сначала шли продукты с совпадением в начале слова. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать данный запрос, т.к. данный запрос будет достаточно часто выполняться (при вводе каждого нового символа в строке поиска), и чем быстрее он будет тем лучше?

Comment: Для начала хотелось бы знать что не устраивает в данный момент. Он медленно выполняется? Если да - то сколько? ДА и в принципе сколько? Может вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией не основываясь ни на чём. И вообще может вам кэш использовать или шаблон запроса.

Comment: Сейчас он выполняется около 0.0637 сек., хотелось бы быстрее. Кеш может спасать только в случае повторных запросов, а что вы имеете в виду по шаблоном запроса?

Comment: Его невозможно оптимизировать. like с процентом в начале в любом случае должен пересмотреть всю таблицу целиком. с ростом таблицы он будет работать все медленнее. необходимо избавляться от нечеткого поиска с середины поля. Можно попробовать использовать полнотекстовый поиск https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html не забыв построить полнотекстовый индекс. Или использовать другие поисковые системы вроде elastic

Comment: @Mike а даст какой-то выигрыш `UNION` где будет первым запросом `LIKE 'para%`, а вторым `LIKE '%para%` + индекс по `name`?  Ведь `LIKE 'para%`  должен юзать индексы

Comment: только не union, а union all, потому что первый будет еще и группировку делать. И я сомневаюсь сильно что это поможет, потому что даже если ему из второй таблицы понадобится одна запись он все равно начнет перебор и видя order by по вычисляемому значению на всякий случай решит получить все строки, отсортировать и только потом применить limit

Comment: Вообще полнотекстовый поиск для того и придуман, что бы быстро искать с любых точек предложения, а не только с начала

Comment: Попробуйте `SELECT id, name 
FROM product 
WHERE LOCATE('para', name) 
ORDER BY LOCATE('para', name) LIMIT 50` - может, выиграете пару миллисекунд... ну и не забудьте создать индекс `(id, name)` или наоборот - для этого запроса порядок полей неважен.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Sphinx suggest](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2016/10/03/2-3-2-feature-built-in-suggests/).